# Cannot install Rfacebook

Tags: r, ubuntu

When i try to install Rfacebook for R version-3.1.3 in ubuntu i get the following error.

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/gadheyan/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/gadheyan/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘Rfacebook’
* removing ‘/home/gadheyan/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rfacebook’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rfacebook’ had non-zero exit status
```

The source packages i've downloaded are located in

```
‘/tmp/RtmpvPtGxz/downloaded_packages’
```

It says that curl and httr packages are not available. So how can i install it so as to use Rfacebook.

Comment: Try installing the packages `curl` and `httr` manually before you can install `Rfacebook`.

Comment: I did that but it ends up in an error. When i installed curl it shows following error:

Comment: --------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/gadheyan/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/home/gadheyan/Downloads/curl_0.9.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: 2 question: first, why are you doing a desktop install instead of a CRAN one. Second, are you using RStudio?

Comment: I am using Rstudio. I have successfully installed Rfacebook. Thanks for the help.